# Use SFP modules for HDMI or Dp TMDS line

Tags: video, hdmi

I just wonder if it's possibile to take four SFP modules and connect them dirrectly to TMDS lines of HDMI output and send such signal via four fiber to other similar end? Is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

HDMI, besides the TDMS lines - which certainly could be bridged over optical - has several sideband signals, notably DDC (I2C) bus.

HDMI needs DDC to not only identify the monitor characteristics (VESA data), but more importantly, to authenticate the receiving device and manage encryption (HDCP) keying. That alone might prevent you from making it work.

Comment: Ok I agree, but I2C or other signals in HDMI is trivial to send or clone. In fact I did that already when transfer HDMI over CAT6 cable. But about SFP I have no clue if they can operate dirrectly with TMDS without SER/DES layer.

Comment: Here's a product that takes the entire HDMI payload down to 1 fiber:https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=24279

Comment: I think it depends on whether SFP needs DC-free coding or not. TMDS is not DC-balanced, while other protocols that use SFP are. That said, it would be kind of wasteful to use 4 SFPs, when just one would do given appropriate payload remux.

Comment: @hacktastical TMDS encoding is DC balanced.

Comment: @hacktastical Well I think about four modules as in HDMI we have four tmds lines, no clue if there is some nice simple IC that could combine them in one signal, moreover cheap single modules are usually 1 to 4Gbps and i'm not quite sure how much bandwidth I need to have for single tmds line to transmit 4k in 4:4:4 mode.

Comment: 2160p60 in 4:4:4 takes 18 Gbps. Three 6 Gbps data links, and one clock link for synchronizing. The clock will be only around 150 MHz though, as there is 40 bits per clock.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, given that all the sideband channels are also transmitted. TMDS lines need DC termination, so they have to be DC terminated while the lines must be AC coupled to the module. There used to exist such modules in SFP form factor that took all HDMI signals in and output over single fiber, and it includes a bidrectional low speed channel for DDC and hotplug etc. These might be based on it : http://www.inneos.com/products/aoc-products/real-4k-adjustable-length-aocs/

Comment: Do you think it's enough just to use pull up resistors on TMDS lines? Also most SFP modules as I check have already internal capacitors. I already ordered 10 x GBIC CISCO FC DS-SFP-FC4G-SW but wonder if need to send some vendor specific instruction via it's I2C bus to be able to run this devices.

Comment: I don’t see how an SFP module could connect to all HDMI signals. The SFP form factor simply doesn’t offer enough IO pins to do that. Can you share a specific example?

Comment: @ThePhoton The important lines are TMDS, so we have four of them and that's my plan is to use four SFP modules. The rest of the signal can go via regular wire or by any other way that allow to exchange DDC, so in fact I2C bus. The challenge here is about high speed signal, termination/impedance and vendor specific command that maybe is needed to send for SFP itself to be able run it.

Comment: @MrHetii, the comment was for Justme, because they said, "There used to exist such modules in SFP form factor that took all HDMI signals in and output over single fiber", which I don't see how it can be possible.

Comment: @ThePhoton http://www.inneos.com/products/eom-products/sh51-02m-barracuda/ so yeah, it is strictly not a standard SFP module, maybe it was presented to me as a SFP module as it resembles one, but it does have more pins.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from other points here, it will also depend on your SFP module. I am not that familiar with SFP moduels, but when you go to some higher speed standards it becomes common to have CDR-circuits in the SFP module. These generally only lock to very narrow ranges of data-rate (say, 9.8 - 11.2 Gbit/s for a 10 gbit/s module). Unless you can disable them (which is sometimes possible) it could be that certain SFP modules don't work.

QSFP+ modules also include 4 SPF+ links internally with WDM, which could allow you to cut down on number of fibers you need to run.